# Identify the source of this Superman video

Tags: dc, superman, episode-identification

From which TV series/movie, this scene has been cut? I don't remember it in *Justice League* or *Superman: The Animated Series*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is from the movie All Star Superman from 2011.

This scene is where he takes her to The Fortress of Solitude after revealing he was Clark Kent. Essentially he found out from Dr. Quintim that he was dying from overdose of solar radiation, in fact this is the movie which shows Superman capable of lifting the heaviest object in the universe, which was 200 Quintillon Tons.  Afterwards he wanted to spend as much time with Lois as possible and revealed himself to her and took her to the Fortress.

From the plot portion of the wikia page.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-Star_Superman_(film)

> Lois doubts his revelation because she had been unable to prove
>   Superman's "Kent" identity herself. Superman takes her to the Fortress
>   of Solitude. During this visit, Superman's secretive behavior and her
>   indirect exposure to alien chemicals heightens Lois's paranoia.
>
> She is startled by Robot 7, shooting it and then Superman with a
>   kryptonite laser.

Comment: Funny enough this is one of the movies I didn't need to research a little for answers... I actually watched this movie before watching the Goku vs Superman Death Battle.